# How to focus() on Expansion Panel in a loop in Angular Material?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a series of Angular Material [expansion panels](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview) in a loop. When a user clicks on a given panel, I want that panel to be the focus on the page.

How can I do this?

This is what i've tried (Angular 8):

html:

```
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let panel of panels; let i = index" >
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
       <mat-panel-title>
          <div (click)="clicked(i)">
             {{panel.Header}}
           </div>
       </mat-panel-title>
     </mat-expansion-panel-header>
   <div #focusOnThisPanel>{{panel.details}}</div>
 </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChildren, QueryList} from '@angular/core';

public panelElements: any

export class GreatComponent implements OnInit {
   @ViewChildren('focusOnThisPanel') focusOnThisPanel: QueryList<ElementRef>

   constructor() {}

   ngAfterViewInit(){
       this.panelElements = this.focusOnThisPanel.map(panel => {
          return panel.nativeElement;
        })
    }

   clicked(i){
      this.panelElements[i].focus()
   }
}
```

This opens the panel, and this code properly registers a click event on the clicked-on panel, but the focus() seems to do nothing--the relevant panel does not come into focus.

So, for example, if the panel was already at the bottom of the page when you click it, it opens down, so the panel details are hidden "below" the page. I want to be sure you can always see the details of any clicked-on panel.

EDIT: Maybe "focus()" is not the right idea here. My goal is to center the clicked on panel vertically on the page--to make sure that it is always visible after it has been clicked. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by focus, you want to open the panel?

Comment: The panel opens already, per Angular Material. I want the opened panel to be the focus of the page. Right now, if a panel is at the bottom of the page, and I click the header, the panel opens down ("below" the page), so you can't see it. I want to be sure that anytime you click the panel you can see the panel details in the middle of the page (or if not the middle, I want to be sure you can always at least see the panel details).

Comment: This is generally the behavior I see with jQuery .focus()--but I haven't gotten it to work with Angular.

Comment: Just add id attribute based on index, like id="customPanel_{{i}}". Then focus it whenever you want by using: document.getElementById('customPanel_1').focus()

Comment: I'd thought that would work too--but it's not. If a panel is at the bottom of page and I click on the header, the details continue to open down, hidden below the page. Even with your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try **[scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)**

The scrollIntoView() method scrolls the specified element into the visible area of the browser window

```
clicked(i){
      this.focusOnThisPanel.toArray()[i].nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
   }
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scrolltoview)

Comment: This is definitely the kind of thing I had in mind. Thank you. With the Angular Material panels, it's a little jerky, and I can't quite get the panel to go all the way to the center (even using "behavior: smooth" and trying the different options). But I'm guessing this is just bc of the interaction with the Material panels, and there's not much to be done.

Comment: I found another one approach try viewportScroller service which provide scrollToAnchor method give a try.

Comment: Do you have an example import and syntax for that? I haven't gotten it to work yet.

Comment: check the stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scrolltoview?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexpansion-overview-example.ts

Comment: Thanks. Got it working. I think it's same as "scrollIntoView". Even putting the "anchor" id at the bottom of the panel, I mostly am not able to get the view to scroll enough to see that anchor element. But it still seems to show the panel more than before these solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The MatExpansionPanel itself does not have a focus() method. However, the MatExpasionPanelHeader does.

If you don't mind focusing the header (which is the correct element to focus anyways) this should work for your case:

```
@ViewChildren(MatExpansionPanelHeader) headers: QueryList<MatExpansionPanelHeader>

focus(index: number): void {
  this.headers[index].focus();
}
```

More detailed example in my [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-vlbss8?file=src%2Fcomponents%2Ffocus-expansion-panel-header%2Ffocus-expansion-panel-header.component.css)

This method works, however i am also wondering why nativeElement.focus() or scrollIntoView doesn't work...